# NotePad ++ : Delete characters before and after specific string

Tags: notepad

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pstambia pstambia 131721 Apr  9  2018 DPT_p_EXT_CONTRACT.deliv
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pstambia pstambia 122364 Nov 28 22:56 DPT_p_EXT_CRC.deliv
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pstambia pstambia 137893 Apr  9  2018 DPT_p_EXT_CRENGLOG.deliv
-rw-r--r-- 1 pstambia pstambia 120692 Oct 29 09:36 DPT_p_EXT_COLLQ4.deliv
-rw-r--r-- 1 pstambia pstambia 118732 Oct 29 09:36 DPT_p_EXT_COLLQ5B.deliv
```

Finally i want to keep only

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pstambia pstambia 131721 Apr  9  2018
```

Comment: Your example does not match your title: please clarify.

Comment: Do you want to keep only 1 line or all the lines without filename?

Comment: You copied this from a Linux/Unix machine into Notepad++ and you want to delete the filenames from Notepad++?

Answer (score 0):

With Notepad++, if you want to delete filenames from each line:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\h+\S+$`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\h+     # 1 or more horizontal spaces
\S+     # 1 or more non space characters
$       # end of line
```

**Result for given example:**

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pstambia pstambia 131721 Apr  9  2018
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pstambia pstambia 122364 Nov 28 22:56
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pstambia pstambia 137893 Apr  9  2018
-rw-r--r-- 1 pstambia pstambia 120692 Oct 29 09:36
-rw-r--r-- 1 pstambia pstambia 118732 Oct 29 09:36
```

Comment: This approach works but take care if you click `Replace All` more than once because it would keep removing the last column. To avoid this you can replace the _Find what:_ with `DPT.*.deliv$`.